# Advice needed for purchasing a new camera or/and lens

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation

My favorite shots are:

1. Reflections
2. Shadows
3. Water droplets and flowing water
4. Clouds and fog
5. Burning tubelight and running fan
6. Macro shots of food and plants

I am not *much* interested in portrait shots and still life (though it doesn't mean that I will never ever shoot them).

Neither I do know whether a SLR suits for this or a DSLR.
What ***properties*** should I look in the camera w.r.t the above shots?

The current camera I have is: 
**Canon PowerShot SX210**

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried the photographs of dark cloudy skies, they didn't look as my eyes could see them, of course I know the difference between the eyes and the camera, but still the photos were not worth the money I have spent on the camera.

I can't achieve the macro shots as I have seen on National Geography channel.

I shot a water puddle once whose one part was under the sunlight and the other under a shadow, the shadowed part became black as I increased the shutter speed.

The minimum aperture I have is f3.1, that too when no zoom is used.

Comment: Any notes on why you're planning on upgrading from Canon PowerShot SX210?

Comment: @ShutterBug I'll edit the question.

Comment: What does "Burning tubelight and running fan" mean?

Comment: @Matt You can say burning bulb or a source of non-natural light. And running fan depicts the motion.

Comment: Hi Anisha. Your question of "what properties should I look for" is a great way to ask on Stack Exchange. But, many of the things in your list are very different from each other. That makes it hard to give it a unique title, and pulls the answers in different directions. It might work better if you edit this question down to a few similar things and ask them all separately. (Asking multiple, smaller questions never hurts!)

Comment: @mattdm I am a newbie w.r.t photography. Please tell me which things are different, so that I can edit them.

Comment: And the reason for the down vote too.

Comment: @Anisha: well, for example, a fan in motion is very different from clouds.

Comment: @mattdm I'll reply when I get back home.

Comment: For food photos, see [this earlier QA](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12665/) — but then, that's different from plant/flower macros. There's other good getting-started questions and answers here if you search, but I know it's hard to look when you're new and don't know exactly what you're looking for. The diversity of your interests suggest a camera with interchangeable lenses (a dSLR or mirrorless). And a number of your concerns center around [dynamic range](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7616/) — dark and light in the same photo — so that's something to learn about.

Comment: @mattdm May I know where is _@ElendilTheTall_ 's answer? :mad:

Comment: Looks like he deleted it. I don't know why, or have any special power or control here — I'm just a regular user like you.

Comment: I deleted it because it was apparently poorly researched on my part - I was unaware that the SX210 has many features I'd ascribed to DSLRs such as manual aperture and shutter speed control. With that in mind, it might be worth looking into the manual settings of your camera more to make sure you're getting the very best out of it, Anisha, before investing in a new camera.

Comment: @mattdm You said "for example, a fan in motion is very different from clouds", I understand that, but I won't be purchasing two different cameras for fan and clouds, though I may consider purchasing two different lenses for the same. Since I have mentioned all my likings, its also possible that someone might know a kind of camera which handles both. I yet don;t know what is a mirrorless camera, but I'll look in Google. Let me see if there is a compact camera with interchangeable lenses.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Thanks for following up, the major problem I see with my camera is the lack of dynamic range handling and a lack of the lowest depth of field i.e f 1.0.

Comment: Dynamic range is an issue with most cameras, but there are perhaps more options to deal with it with a DSLR. Massive depth of field is definitely a problem with all point and shoots, and phone cameras; it's a function of a smaller sensor, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all honesty, a lot of the work you like to do depends a lot on technique, though when it comes to macro work, it is definitely good to have top-notch equipment.

If you really want to do some fantastic macro work, I suggest any of the following (+ Canon DSLR):

- Canon Macro lenses (50mm, 100mm, etc.); if you want to get really close, the MPE5 is amazing -- up to 5x magnification, with a ridiculously close focusing distance.
- Tamron 180mm Macro (I have this one, love it to pieces), but they have others that are great too
- Sigma should have a good one too
- Extension tubes for existing lenses (to reduce focusing distance and increase magnification)

Next, you need to realize that a big sensor = tiny depth of field, which means that unless you can shut down to f/99 with a ton of light, you're only going to have a little bit in focus. The way around that is to do *focus-stacking*: this is a method where you take a series of images with different focus, and then you join them together to get an image with the subject entirely in focus. Not the easiest of work, but in a way, it's similar to HDR or other stacking techniques.

Second, a ring flash would be a great idea for macro work as it enables you to get light up-close to your subject that is nicely distributed. (Don't go for the really cheapies, you want a quality flash that won't harm your camera...)

As to some of your other likes:

- Reflections

  - (Assuming in water) A circular polarizer helps here because you can turn it to a point that you will either see the reflection on the water, or you will see through the water. Very useful to have.
- Shadows
- Water Drops

  - Macro lens is great for this
- Water (Flowing)

  - a long exposure is the best option, something your camera can already do. If there is too much light, a polarizer or ND filter can be used to further darken the camera's view to allow for longer exposures without blowing out the scene.
- Clouds and Fog

  - Remember, your camera exposes for the middle (so white often becomes gray). Try switching your metering mode (spot, evaluative, etc.) but also adjust exposure compensation. Better yet, go full-on manual and set the exposure yourself.
  - Side note: unless you have something well-defined in the clouds/fog, any camera will have difficulty focusing. You may have to focus manually.
- Burning Tubelight / Running Fan

  - Long exposure, again, something your camera can do. Although a DSLR has a bigger sensor, so it should have reduced noise vs. your existing camera.

Hope that helps. Can your current camera do a lot of what you're looking for, yes, to a certain degree, but it is most limited in the macro arena where you can't get a lot of magnification out of the lens. Noise is also going to be a limiting factor, in that it isn't long until the ISO causes unbearable grain. DSLRs get around this by having that big sensor, but they are also more flexible with regard to the interchangeable lens, letting you pick what really, really, really will work best for the scene.

Comment: Thanks Kerri, You said _"you need to realize that a big sensor = tiny depth of field"_ I am not sure if I understand that correctly, all I know is if I have f 1.0, that's going to blur out the background of the subject, is that correct?

Comment: I'll look up what is _"circular polarizer"_, but for that I guess I'll have to purchase new camera body. You said _"your camera exposes for the middle"_, what does that mean? BTW, I always shoot in fully manual.

Comment: Manual focus is a new thing for me, I'll look up how to do it, thanks. And AFA the burning tubelight is concerned, I have had those shots before, but the background in the photo turns out to be black when I go increasing the shutter speed, that's the problem.

Comment: I'll go one-by-one here: First, the larger the sensor, the shorter your depth of field, which is essentially the part of the image that is in focus. Your aperture (F/#) also has a part to play in this, but f/8 on a large sensor will still have a bit of background blur, whereas f/8 on a compact camera sensor will have everything in sharp focus. So f/1 will blur your background, but a larger sensor will blur the background more (and leave less in focus). This can be a good or bad thing, depending on your creative needs. For Macro work, it's hard to balance aperture (DoF) vs. light vs. focus.

Comment: A circular polarizer is a lens attachment (and you may find some that work on compact bodies) that deflects light coming in at certain angles. This can mean bluer skies and such, but also works wonders with reflections in water or glass where you may wish to see through the glass (but not see your reflection), or with water where you want to see the reflection, but not what's underneath the water. Depending on your camera, there may be filter adapters that you could get.

Comment: Manual Focus is wonderful, _if_ you have decent eyes and _if_ your camera permits accurate viewing of your focus. Some cameras will zoom in automatically so you can focus better, but manual focus is _far_ better with an optical viewfinder (IMO) -- except that you have to trust your eyes that you can see when focus is achieved.

Comment: For your dark background problem, you could either let the exposure sit for a while longer with no other lights, or you could "paint" the background with flashes/lights which would cause the background to become visible (assuming a bright enough light), OR, you could use two exposures -- one for your tubelight and another taken without it, exposed for the background and then merge the two in post.

Comment: Thanks for being too helpful :hattip: I have also noticed that when I zoom to the maximum in my camera, the f raises to 4.5, automatically. Is that a flaw or can be advantageous in some way?

Comment: @Anisha, the reason your aperture changes to f/4.5 as you zoom to the maximum is because your lens isn't capable of a constant aperture throughout the zoom range. This is a feature of many lenses, including various professional lenses, because it is easier to make a lens that has a variable aperture than a constant one. (The lenses also tend to be lighter and cheaper.)  There's no way around it, unfortunately, except to grab a lens that has a constant aperture (which means that as you zoom your exposure don't change), but these are typically expensive.

Comment: and what is this _"Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"_. I don't want to move anything to chat! That'll scatter the info.

Comment: You have been too helpful. Now, understanding the zoom and the focal length is altogether a different topic, for which it is better for me to start a new thread. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

**Anisha, your camera is capable of taking photos of all of those subjects quite well.**

You can do **better in the macro department with a camera that can focus closer** such as the SX200 or SX130, but that is about it. The [SX200](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/canon/sx200/review) for example has a 0cm (zero) minimum focus-distance so it can focus on the dust on its lens!

DSLR macro lenses can get close but none that close and they actually lose substantial depth-of-field compared to your camera. You do not seem to need a camera with fast-response time or low-light performance which are the primary reasons people go with a DSLR.

**The best way you can improve your photography is to learn more.** You cannot buy your way out of bad photos. Additionally, when you learn more you will know better what to look for in a camera so that it suits your needs.

I would suggest a photography course or at least a book covering all the basic principles. [Reader's Digest Complete Photography Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0762102926) is a classic and easily available in libraries.

Comment: Thanks Itai, I'd like to know what do you mean by "fast-response time", in what context? My problem is "high dynamic range" which I have mentioned in the OP. Definitely I need more practice, I ve just started the search for the future camera. Can "HDR" be also solved somehow with this camera?

Comment: *Response time* is the time it takes for the camera to take a shot once you press the shutter. DSLRs currently lead by far in this respect but it makes no practical difference if you are shooting still subjects. All cameras have a limited dynamic range, so there will be always be circumstances (as you describe) where ANY camera will fail. Going to a camera with a larger sensor will help up to a limit. Beyond that, then you have to go with HDR which works best with still subjects.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment on ElendilTheTall's answer you say:

> They say DSLR is too heavy, you can't carry it all along, so what to do in these situations?

That was a significant factor in my decision *not* to get a DSLR when looking to upgrade from a compact camera.  I would probably be able to take better photographs with a DSLR than my current camera, but I would have less opportunity to take them because the size and weight would mean I wouldn't take it with me.

My camera is one of the micro 4/3rds range (Olympus Pen E-PL1 to be precise).  It's basically a decent lens with a biggish sensor stuck on the end.  The idea is to take a DSLR and remove the mirror.  It has interchangeable lenses, fully manual mode, larger sensor than a compact, and - relevant to your comment - I can *easily* take photographs one-handed (whilst using the other arm to ensure that the shot I'm taking *doesn't* include a small child jumping in to the lake).  Possibly the major disadvantage is the lack of optical viewfinder so seeing what's on the screen in *extremely* bright light can be difficult (though you can buy electronic viewfinders that, I've heard, partially make up for that lack).

Whilst probably not of professional quality, I'd say that I've gotten good photographs and significantly better ones than I did with my old compact camera (which was itself a pretty good one - for its age!).  Specifically, with the shutter-priority mode I got some good shots of running water (had a lot of that recently here in Norway!), and I've also gotten some nice insect photos with "macro" mode (not actually anything other than focussing really close up), and with bracketing I've been able to get better cloud shots than I used to (I use bracketing because I haven't a clue what settings are best to use).

There'll probably be lots of advice about getting a DSLR, and I write this knowing that it'll be countered by that so you'll get a balanced opinion overall!  In short, if getting a better camera means that you leave it behind most of the time, then it wasn't the right camera to get, and knowing that there is a halfway house (something I only found out about by chance) may be useful to you in making your decision.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Andrew. What is the maximum and minimum 'f' in your compact camera, I'll like to know. My camera doesn't have a viewfinder too, I haven't even felt the need to use it till now. If you can change lenses too, then why would you need the DSLR? I'll look up the camera you mentioned, but also the point is, that whatever camera I purchase next, will be final for my rest of the life, unfortunately.

Comment: Here's a link to a review of this camera: http://www.dpreview.com/products/olympus/slrs/oly_epl1 (that site seems popular on this site for reviews).  The 'f' depends on the lens.  I seem to be able to get between 3.5 and 22 depending on the lens and the zoom.  I'm very happy with this camera.

Comment: I have the 3.1 when there is zero zoom, the maximum is f8.0. I just read your camera supports RAW :) and it looks promising! I would like to ask on what basis do you decide that you'll be purchasing Olympus or some other brand? I ve heard the cannon is the best? And there is Nikon too? Too many choices!

Comment: @Anisha: When I was thinking about getting a new camera, I wanted something with more control than my compact, but when I tried a friend's DSLR I was amazed at how big and heavy it was.  Then I saw an advert for the Sony NEX5 and thought, "That's the sort of thing I need.".  But then I compared the various available cameras on that dpreview site and the Olympus came out best for the things that I thought important.  There are more of these cameras available now so it may not be the best anymore.

Comment: That means brand name doesn't matter, features do!

Comment: @Anisha: I wouldn't go quite that far.  There are certain brands that I feel have been in the game long enough that they know what the issues are, so I'll look carefully at what they produce.  So my _instinct_ would be to prefer an Olympus over a Sony, say.  But I also know that my instinct isn't based on very much _experience_ so I don't trust it all that much.  It's all about gathering evidence until you have enough evidence to make a decision.  Some factors count a lot, some factors don't.  But very few factors don't count at all.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I guessed you would answer something like that. I have just started the search, won't be purchasing anything till I am too much confident about what I am doing. :)